# how http server received file from client

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, http

I have written code for sending client user passwords to an HTTP server for verification via HTTP. I generate the query string (containing `usr`, `pwd`) and send the request to the server. That works.

But now I have to send a file (`text/xml`) to that server. I don't know how it can be done.

Do we have to write some code on the server or only in the client?

What are the mechanisms on the server for accepting file and on the client for sending files?

Comment: i written code in which the client take the user & pwd and generate query string and send that to server ,the server give the response.but when i have to send file to server what we do for server that it take that file from client.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP protocol is really simple, actually:

1. the client sends a line containing HTTP method name, URL and protocol version
2. the client sends an RFC822 header containing request parameters and, if a data block follows, details about the data block.
3. the client sends the data block
4. the server sends a line containing protocol version, status code and message
5. the server sends an RFC822 header containing response parameters and, if a data block follows (or the client performed a HEAD request), details about the data block
6. the server sends the data block, unless the method is HEAD.
7. the connection is either torn down, or the protocol restarted.

Typically, servers will understand at least these methods:

- GET (client does not send data block, server sends data block)
- HEAD (same as GET, but server omits response data block)
- POST (client sends data block, server responds with data block)
- PUT (client sends data block, server does not send data block)

There is some implied semantics in the choice of method, in that GET requests never modify server state and their results may be cached and reused (which is what allows the browser to go back and forth between pages), while POST requests do change server state -- incidentally, this is what you do when you upload a file.

So, in order to send a file, prepare a POST or PUT request (depending on whether you expect a reply document, or if a simple acknowledgement status code is sufficient), which consists of the request line, the headers containing extra protocol info ("Host:", "User-Agent:", ...), the headers describing the file ("Content-Type:", "Content-Length:", ...), an empty line, and the file contents, and send that over a TCP connection, then read back the status line, the response headers and the response file (if you asked for one).

Answer (score 1):

If its a XML file it is easy.

You can add `Content-Type: text/xml` in the HTTP header and append the XML file data after the `\r\n\r\n` of the HTTP header and send it via the socket to the webserver.

The webserver will understand from the HTTP header that it contains XML file and takes the file. In the case of a bnary file, you will need to convert it to `base64`.

For example I have used a buffer to store the http request. Now if you send this buffer to the socket connected to the webserver, the FileName.xml will be saved in the webserver. For this to work the upload.php has to able to work with POST data.
The boundary is to show the boundary between the data and is needed by the HTTP protocol. It can be any random generated number and make sure the start boundary and the close boundary numbers are equal. Also content length is the length of the file.
    `

```
char buf[2048] =  "POST http://www.nameofyoursite.com/upload.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                                                "Host: www.nameofyoursite.com\r\n"
                                                "Content-Type: multipart-form-data, boundary=1234567\r\n"
                                                "Content-Length: 15\r\n\r\n"
                    "--1234567\r\n"
                    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"FileName.xml\"\r\n"
                    "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n"
                    "<xml>This is a test</xml>\r\n"
                    "--1234567--\r\n";
```

`

Comment: thks one more queries what we have to code in server side that it receive the file...cilent send the file we have to check the response from server .so what server do at that side.

Comment: Yes u need to have server side code which does the copying. For example you can make a php file which does this. The main code needed is given below.
`$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path);`

Comment: thks for the code, but here the server based on .net using vs2010 .how the server received the client file through http request by the client side.

Comment: You have only added tags as 'C' and 'http'...Add 'visual-studio' and 'visual-studio-2010' so that someone who knows this can help you.

Comment: You can send binary data without encoding just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server's application how to load the file.
You may need to send the file using the HTTP "POST" method instead of "GET".

```
POST /your_uri HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yourhost.com
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-length: 41

filename=test.xml&data=yoururlencodeddata
```

The server application may expect files encoded with "multipart/form-data" boundaries, something like that:

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaBb01x

--AaBb01x
content-disposition: form-data; name="yourfield"

Your field data
--AaBb01x
content-disposition: form-data; name="yourfilefield"; filename="filename.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<root>your xml data</root>
--AaBb01x
```

Comment: it's necessary to use cURL or json or other api for sending file to http server.

Comment: check the url http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/281070 it's near by solution but it's for php and i have to do in visual stdio .net ..how it can be done ??